# How to authenticate a gRPC call for the Assistant SDK?

Tags: swift, macos, ssl, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I'm using the Swift gRPC library (which curiously isn't listed on gRPC's website, but there is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift) for it) to build an implementation of the Google Assistant SDK for macOS. I've gotten my OAuth2 credentials and token, and am trying to make the initial request to begin a conversation, however it fails to do so.

I always get the error `Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1Alpha1_EmbeddedAssistantClientError error 1.)` and `gRPC.CallError error 1.`

I ran Wireshark to try and debug the issue, and I saw the my computer *is* attempting to establish a connection but eventually ends up aborting the connection. I think it may be due to a TLS issue, but I'm not sure if that actually is the case or how to fix it.

I noticed the service initialization function has an overload where you specify certificates, but I don't know what to put there (or if that function needs to be used at all)

```
typealias AssistantService = Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1Alpha1_EmbeddedAssistantService
typealias AssistantCall = Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1Alpha1_EmbeddedAssistantConverseCall
typealias AudioInConfig = Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1alpha1_AudioInConfig
typealias AudioOutConfig = Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1alpha1_AudioOutConfig
typealias ConverseRequest = Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1alpha1_ConverseRequest
typealias ConverseConfig = Google_Assistant_Embedded_V1alpha1_ConverseConfig    

var service: AssistantService?
var currentCall: AssistantCall?

public init() {
    service = AssistantService(address: Constants.ASSISTANT_API_ENDPOINT)
    let token = "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY)!)"
    service?.metadata = Metadata(["authorization" : token])
}

func initiateRequest() {
    var request =   ConverseRequest()
    request.config = ConverseConfig()

    var audioInConfig = AudioInConfig()
    audioInConfig.sampleRateHertz = 16000
    audioInConfig.encoding = .linear16
    request.config.audioInConfig = audioInConfig


    var audioOutConfig = AudioOutConfig()
    audioOutConfig.sampleRateHertz = 16000
    audioOutConfig.encoding = .linear16
    audioOutConfig.volumePercentage = 50
    request.config.audioOutConfig = audioOutConfig

    do {
        currentCall = try service?.converse(completion: { result in
            print("Result code \(result.statusCode)")
            print("Result description \(result.description)")
            print("Metadata \(String(describing: result.initialMetadata))")
            print("Status message \(result.statusMessage ?? "Error")")
            print("Obj description \(String(describing: result))")
            print("result \(result)")
        })

        try currentCall?.send(request) { err in
            print("Error in initial request: \(err)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Initial error \(error)")
    }
}
```

This is what the Wireshark for it looks like, if it is any help:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the `roots.pem` file found [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/tree/master/Examples/Datastore/PackageManager) to my project and use it as follows:

```
let u = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "roots", withExtension: "pem")!
let certificate = try! String(contentsOf: u)
let token = "Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY)!)"
service = AssistantService(address: Constants.ASSISTANT_API_ENDPOINT, certificates: certificate, host: nil)
service?.metadata = Metadata(["authorization" : token])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see some [new examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/tree/0.3.2/Examples/Google) in the grpc-swift project that call Google Cloud APIs. I've simplified client creation to use TLS by default and to embed a default roots.pem in the library binary. You can see that [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/0.3.2/Examples/Google/Datastore/Sources/main.swift#L67) along with usage of an [auth library](https://github.com/google/auth-library-swift) that supports Google Application Default Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Swift, and your Wireshark screen shot may be masking important information, but I believe one or both of the following may be the problem:

1. `Constants.ASSISTANT_API_ENDPOINT` needs to be set to "embeddedassistant.googleapis.com". (It isn't clear, but I don't think the destination address shown in Wireshark is the API endpoint, which it should be.)
2. `Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY` should be the auth token that you've gotten as part of the OAuth2 dance. Keep in mind that it expires (usually after an hour) and you'll need to get a new one. I don't know how Swift configuration works for it, but in others you don't need to specify the "Bearer" part of the auth information since you're not passing the header specifically.

Comment: Yeah I do have the API endpoint set to that URL. (I covered up the screenshot in order to hide my IP). And yeah for the auth token, I'm refreshing it every time it expires. Also what do you mean by the "Basic" part of the auth information?

Comment: Whoops. Brain-o on my part. Meant "Bearer" and this has been fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing "Bearer" doesn't seem to fix the problem either

Answer (score 0):

Took the latest
pod 'SwiftGRPC' 
pod 'SwiftProtobuf'
version using pod update and it got fixed .

Installing BoringSSL 10.0.6 (was 10.0.5 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing SwiftGRPC 0.5.1 (was 0.4.3 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing gRPC-Core 1.12.0 (was 1.11.0 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing Realm 3.7.6 (was 3.7.4 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing RealmSwift 3.7.6 (was 3.7.4 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)

Then all i need was create the session/service with my certificate.

let certPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "XYZ", withExtension: "pem")!
let certificate = try! String(contentsOf: certPath)
service = Pronounce_PronounceServiceClient(address: Constants.ServerApi.grpcBaseUrl, certificates: certificate)